# Is it important make use of standard iOS components?

Tags: ios, components

We are creating an iOS app that does not look like any other app you would find in the app store.

My question is, am I allowed to create custom components such as header bars, tab bars, tables etc. for my app and not get rejected by Apple when publishing the app to the app store?

Months of thought and planning has gone into the UI and flow of the app, so the user experience would be superb, we're just concerned about how apple feels about custom apps/components like these?

Regards

Comment: Don't worry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing inherently wrong with creating an app that's got a completely different look and feel to everything else.

*But* what I would advise is that you try to use the built-in components as much as possible. In recent versions of iOS Apple have introduced a number of APIs to let you customise their look and feel significantly, and some of the most innovative UIs out there are simple table and collection views that have been hacked to pieces.

This is because Apple's built in components have logged many hundreds of thousands (if not millions) of hours of real-world testing and use, and are thus vastly more stable and field-tested than a totally custom component. Plus, they often have various built in features (such as a scroll view's bounce) that are hard to replicate on your own.

So definitely customise your interface as much as you like, but while you're doing it think about whether you can harness the built-in `UIKit` classes rather than totally re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

More and more custom controls appear for iOS every day. If it is so good as you say, Apple will be happy to accept it. Don't worry.

Also take a look at these [cocoacontrols](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/)

Answer (score 0):

As said before, Apple will not have a problem with that .. as long as you don't use any private APIs. If you are developing these components on your own, you will have to make sure that these will work in future releases (which is not necessarily a bad point) . This may be a problem with third party components, as they may not be continued (or supported in future releases).